# React-datepicker TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker

I use react-datepicker in my project. I can pick date from calendar but when I key up in input I get this error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Here is the code how can i fixed it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-browser-52m1b

I also want the calendar disabled like the others when I click the save button. How can I do this?

Comment: recreate the error because i cannot see any errors

Comment: As the OP said, if you input date with keyboard you get the error @GayatriDipali

Comment: It warns you about the ref usage: Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Not sure how to fix it but you can try exporting Input by using export default forwardRef(Input)

Comment: @SinanYaman it's not working :/